# php ERR TOO MANY REDIRECTS

Tags: php

I am a beginner at php and I get this error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. I guess this happens because of my `require` and `header`.

And after that I need to use the variables of `main php` so I'm calling it by using `require` then I'm sending necessary information fulfilling the form then I get the error of `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

`main.php`

```
if $mdStatus=1 || $mdStatus=2 || $mdStatus=3 || $mdStatus=4) {
    header ('Location: success.php'); exit;
```

`success.php`

```
require('payment.php');
$name="ISBANK";
```

So how can i solve this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is because, you include main in your success page.

```
In main page, Set $mdstatus=0 before redirect.
```